# Is "home patch" completely equivalent to "hometown"?

Tags: phrases, nouns, synonyms, british-english

I heard this expression "home patch" referring to "hometown" from a recent BBC Documentary. Since I am not a native English speaker, I am wondering about whether it is completely equivalent to "hometown". Is it widely used in both American English and Britain English?

Comment: It's not idiomatic in the US, and is apt to be poorly understood.

Comment: Who was using this expression?  Was it a police officer?

Comment: It is from an reporter. See this radio on 1:33: "I have come back to my home pay the week after the vote." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7kjg4nXsYA

Comment: Watching the video, I think the reporter is referring to the patch he worked back when he was a junior  reporter starting his career.

Answer (score 1):

**Patch** to mean an area where one operates (especially for police officers, criminals or salesmen) is common in informal BrE.

It could sometimes equate to a hometown but not always.

> 3.1 British informal **An area for which someone is responsible or in which they operate**
> : *we didn’t want any secret organizations on our patch*
>
> More example sentences
> :
> *A radical shake up of rural policing in the district will see the return of local Bobbies patrolling a beat and being responsible safety and security **on their patch**.
>
> Every now and then, an experience would serve as a reminder that intelligent marine mammals can be aggressive as well as friendly; that you must operate with respect in what **is their patch**.
>
> One woman **on my patch** called police fifty times in twelve months, and they attended every time. That's fifty crimes of violence for the politicians to wave about.*
> — http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/patch

Comment: What used to be referred to as their "manor" in the old cop shows...

Comment: @max-williams exactly

Comment: Also birdwatchers often have a "local patch". "Home patch" is rarely used but understood as a local patch very near the home.

Answer (score -1):

One meaning of *patch* is a small plot of land, one often used for gardening. The word is often used with some particular cultivation, notably melons. For a brief discussion of a watermelon **patch** and its role in your survival after armageddon, go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPfmG2WqiBs). Earlier references are more likely about the literal meaning. Thus from [*Poultry, Garden and Home, Volume 3*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sChJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22home%20patch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD67Lm1Y3OAhXM5iYKHW_bC-QQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22home%20patch%22&f=false) (1896)

> We live in town and have a **home patch**, and in the early summer, as
>   soon as fruiting is over, we have "cow-peas" planted between the rows,
>   thus utilizing the soil the year around.

Note that the writer's home town and his home patch are different. The former is his residence, and the latter provides food for his home. The phrase has taken on a figurative meaning as the familiar place in which one is comfortable.  Consider the 1997 [headline](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/rugby-union-moore-on-home-patch-as-wales-ring-changes-1248035.html) from the British newspaper the *Independent*:

> Rugby Union: Moore on **home patch** ....

The article says that rugby player Steve Moore "will be returning to familiar territory as he makes his home debut for Wales" when his team plays in Wrexham, a town in Wales. Moore wasn't born in Wrexham, but he grew up there.

An equivalent expression for one's home base -- one that the Ngram viewer reports as newer -- is *home turf*.

Comment: I'd note that the Poultry, Home and Garden example is from an American publication and doesn't *necessarily* attest to a 'home patch' being used to denote a vegetable patch in British English.

Comment: @Spagirl A few minutes spent in the Ngram viewer finds *patch* in British publications in the sense of horticulture. The *OED* doesn't report that use as acerage, so perhaps it's a later import from the colonies. In any case, it's figurative use on both sides of the Atlantic means home ground or familiar territory.

Comment: Yes, I agree that 'patch' has a horticultural application. I was underlining that the example of '*home* patch' as horticultural was American in source rather than British. What triggered my response was HotLicks' assertion that the idiom isn't known in the USA. It always seems improbable that a usage exclusive to one side of the pond (if it is/was) should lead to an idiom that is only known on the other side. OED does give 'patch' as 'A small piece of ground, especially one used for gardening' and 'British informal An area for which someone is responsible or in which they operate'.

Comment: @Spagirl - "Home patch", in the sense used in the *Poultry, Garden and Home* reference, clearly means a garden behind the house.  "A patch of ground" is idiomatic in the US, but it inevitably refers to a physical piece of ground, usually small, and generally agricultural.  "Home turf", on the other hand, *would* be taken to refer to one's home locality.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I understood the PG&H reference. What I didn't understand was how it helped us get from 1890s american gardening to the usage in the question, which I understood from your comment not to be idiomatic in the USA.

Comment: @Spagirl - There are many idioms that have not crossed the ocean either direction.

Comment: @HotLicks I've found this thread very confusing and full of apparent non-sequitur. I'm obviously failing to communicate my point, and by persisting would appear inappropriately dogmatic. Be assured, however, that I never doubted that not all idioms cross oceans, that the PG&H reference was to a garden near a house or and that 'patch' can mean a cultivated area in British English.  I can't tell you how confused I am at the miscommunication. Spagirl out.